# My shell-script is not running on android

Tags: android, bash, shell, sh

I am trying to run the following simple **shell-script on android**:

```
#!/system/bin/sh 
echo "Hello World!"
```

I named the file "*test*", and place it in "*/system/bin/*" .. I change the *permission* to *755* and the *group* to *shell* ..

now when I try to run the script: `test`, it shows:

```
sh: test: No such file or directory
```

I can see the file in there and when I run `bash test` or `sh test` it works ..

what is the problem ?

Comment: What's the path of your `sh`? Check if it is really `/system/bin/sh`. Also, it is `#!/bin...`.

Comment: @fedorqui: `which` command is showing me `/system/bin/sh` ..

Comment: OK so this part is fine. What about the `#!`?

Comment: @fedorqui: yes .. [#!] is already there (it just doesn't appear where highlighting the text as code), and I changed the folder to /bin/sh .. however, same message appear !!!

Comment: How do you execute the script? Try using the full path of the file.

Comment: @fedorqui: no .. having the full path as _./system/bin/test_, it doesn't work too ..

Comment: No, I mean the script `test`. How do you call it?

Comment: @fedorqui: i just call the script name that is _test_ .. note that I am already _su_

Comment: To execute a script, use `./test` if you are in the directory or `/path/to/test` if you are not. Also `/system/bin/sh /path/to/test` can do it as well.

Comment: @fedorqui: the first two : _./test_ and _/path/to/test_ do not work .. but when I run _bash test_ or _sh test_ from anywhere it works .. so ...

Comment: So it means that it does not work with `/system/bin/sh` as interpreter. When you indicate another one (bash or sh) it does. Try to change `/system/bin/sh` to the path of bash.

Comment: @fedorqui: when changing the directory to _/system/xbin/_, the same message appears again .. however, when I exit the _su account_, I get message saying: _/system/bin/sh: test: no such file or directory_ .. !!

Comment: If you get `_/system/bin/sh no such file or directory` it means that you are not using `#!/system/bin/sh` but `_/system/bin/sh`. Change it!

Comment: @fedorqui: sorry for the spelling mistake .. the **underscore** is not there in the message

Comment: If I understand properly, you are trying to define another command by storing it in `/system/bin`. Try to use other names, as `test` is a reserved one (normally). Also, maybe (not sure) you need to reload your session so that it detects the new command.

Comment: @fedorqui: that is exactly what I am trying to do .. btw, the real command-name is not test, but thanks for the tip .. about reloading my session .. do u mean exit the adb connection and connect again within the same terminal (i.e: cmd), or exit the main terminal and open it again and then run the adb shell from start ?

Comment: I would try the bigger one (restart user's session), but I am not very sure. For the rest, I just can hope someone comes and give more advice, as mine are over, can't figure out what else can be happening.

Comment: @fedorqui: it is not working again .. but thanks really for your troubleshooting .. the thing is I have a similar file .. typically the same .. same in everything except in its command-name .. it is working fine and from anywhere .. don't know why this file doesn't work the same way ..!!!!!

Comment: Try to compare them line by line, any small difference can be important! Also check the differences on permissions and the owner, as well as the way they are executed.

Answer (score 1):

Do not call it “test” because that’s a shell built-in command. Shells will call internal builtins in preference over external utilities.

Rename it to /system/bin/testx and call it as “testx” and see whether that works.

Other common pitfalls on android: 「#!/system/bin/sh」 and most directories are mounted “noexec”. But both of these do not apply to your script if you put it to /system/bin/ anyway.